# CDI and EJB mix with glassfish 3.1

Tags: java, dependency-injection, ejb, cdi, glassfish-3

I have two application deployed on glassfish - application A and B.

Both are deployed as war package, application B uses some components from application A.

Now in application A I have an interface:

```
public interface BusinessInterface() extends SomeOtherInterface {
    void someAction();
}
```

I have 3 implementations of this interface - two in application A, one in application B: `BusinessInterfaceA1, BusinessInterfaceA2, BusinessInterfaceB`

As long as all of them are CDIBeans, everything is fine - I'm using custom @Qualifier annotations (@BusinessInterfaceA1, @BusinessInterfaceA2) and @Default annotation for B's implementation to distinguish them.

But now I need both application's A implementations to be Stateful EJBs and this is where it becomes funny.

When I just add @Statefull annotation on both implementations, a I got something like this:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049
```

details:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to convert ejbRef for ejb BusinessInterfaceA1 to a business object of type interface SomeOtherInterface
```

How can I fix it? I need all implementations to be avaliable in a way I could inject them like

```
@Inject @SomeAnnotation private BusinessInterface businessInterface;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [bug](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16186) in Glassfish 3.1. The workaround is, to mark implementation with all required interfaces, e.g.:

```
@Statefull/@Stateless
public class BusinessInterfaceImpl implements BusinessInterface, SomeOtherInterface {
   // implementation
}
```

Even `BusinessInterface` extends `SomeOtherInterface`, and from Java specs its useless to do that, but as a workaround for that bug it works.

Another solution is to use Glassfish 4.0

Comment: It's been a long time since I needed it, I don't have proper environment to test it right now, but thanks anyway.